# Unable to update from AppCenter

Tags: updates, appcenter

Is there anyone else experiencing this error when trying to load updates from the AppCenter?

```
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages is not (yet) available (File has unexpected size (721920 != 721972). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 202.90.159.172 80]
Hashes of expected file:
 - Filesize:721972 [weak]
 - SHA256:22f3325fcea25c25dad365e601ebd20fb2820aeca122a2dd4dc0ced9596329d6
 - SHA1:8e47e4bf3cffbfabdfb81a25af958946143da0c0 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:cefedd2648d716c724947201b9af4ad2 [weak]
Release file created at: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 08:44:28 +0000
)
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons is not (yet) available ()
E: http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons is not (yet) available ()
```

This happens to me today when I opened the AppCenter. I was hoping that I can get updates from the packages that I installed.

Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: The message itself offers an explanation: `Mirror sync in progress?`. I would try to wait an hour or so and see if it gets fixed.

Comment: FYI updates work on my machine, just updated 4 packages (libgranite etc).

Comment: Try updating from the command line as well: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade `

Answer (score 1):

Probably be the mirror from your packages, I usually setup to the us servers.

Just go to /etc/apt

Once you are here just open the file **source.list**, No the one that it's source.list.d

Or you can do it via terminal, using any text editor:

Nano

> sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list

Atom

> sudo atom /etc/apt/source.list

Now you will see all the apt link that Elementary use download the updates

For example:

> deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

Now just change the region from ph to any other, in this case us

> deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

Hopefully this works, maybe it's a little bit slower but you can try another servers.

Check the mirror list [HERE](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirror)